# Preserving YAML space while expanding variables in CloudFormation template

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have a section in my CloudFormation template that looks like this:

```
  Employees:
    - hr: 
        - office: !Join [ '_', [ 'region', !Ref 'AWS::Region' ] ]
```

When I bring up the stack and convert the values in `Employees` to `yaml` using the golang `gopkg.in/yaml.v2` package, the whitespace is stripped away so that the output looks like this:

```
        - hr: 
        - office: region_us-east-1
```

When I ask yaml to preserve the spacing by doing something like this:

```
  Employees:
    - hr: >
        - office: !Join [ '_', [ 'region', !Ref 'AWS::Region' ] ]
```

The expansion in the template doesn't take place, BUT the whitespace is preserved, and the output looks like:

```
        - hr: 
          - office: !Join [ '_', [ 'region', !Ref 'AWS::Region' ] ]
```

How can I both expand the CloudFormation variable and preserve the yaml indentation?

Comment: Sadly, its not clear what you want to do. Your second example with `>` just creates a string. What's wrong with the first example? Expansion works, so it seems its ok?

Comment: @Marcin in the first example the leading whitespace is removed so I end up with what's in my second example.  `office` should be nested under `hr`, not a new entry.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the resulting string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be more a problem with the golang package you're using than it is with CloudFormation itself, but you could probably work around the problem by using explicit JSON syntax where the whitespace gets stripped out. This would result in something like this (untested):

```yaml
Employees:
    - hr: [ { office: !Join [ '_', [ 'region', !Ref 'AWS::Region' ] ] } ]
```